# how to check and change elements of array in 2d array?

Tags: python, python-3.8, tic-tac-toe

I started a game project(small project) on Python3 but i dunno how to   iterate 2d array and change 'em. IS IT POSSIBLE TO write a game logic (Tic-Tac-Toe ''3 symbols on one line wins'') with 2d array with 0 index and if it changed to 'O' or 'X' replace current iterating element index to one or two ?!. in two words - matrix of 9 elements would been checked and if it element index was changed change an element(i dont know how to make visualization of game [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK1Q6.png), I only worked on JS-HTML-CSS and can make it there, BUT PYTHON3 (IS NEW TO ME) I DONT KNOW!!!)

My array but error occurs

[image: 1]

```
array = []
def createMatrix(mtrx):
    mtrx = [[mtrx[i][j].append(0) for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
    print(mtrx)
createMatrix(array)
```

Comment: not an answer to your actual question here, but the website realpython has a tutorial on an implementation of a tic-tac-toe game that could teach you a lot: https://realpython.com/tic-tac-toe-python/

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text/code/errors. Post them as [formatted text](/help/formatting)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/843953/pranav-hosangadi im wroted it like code under the main question !!! what anout you are talking when u said formatted question !!!!!

Comment: is it True or Better as professional or just good code i wrote down below  - `                   
 def createMatrix(mtrx):
       mtrx = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
       print(mtrx)
`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a= []
>>> a.append(9)
>>> print(a.append(9))
None
>>>
```

What's going on here? Well, `list.append` returns `None`. As fo most functions which *mutate* data rather than generating new values. You can see this in your code with:

```
[[mtrx[i][j].append(0) for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
```

Those indices also don't exist yet, so you will get an index error.

You likely want:

```
[[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
```

Which generates:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

As an alternative, you could do the following, but that isn't better than `matrix = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]`.

```
matrix = []
for _ in range(3):
  row = []
  for _ in range(3):
    row.append(0)
  matrix.append(row)
```

Comment: thank you @Chris, but i dont understand properly what you said about mutating(or linking to old variable which was created earlier?!)

Comment: Your list is _empty_. You can't access elements by index because no elements _exist_. Also, the list comprehension collects the value of an expression, so even if you didn't have the index issue, you'd just be collecting `None` which is the value of `some_list.append(some_val)`.

Comment: why I cant create an array with `for` loop and when I iterating in first loop create a second loop and in there cppend an element to my empty array ?!

Comment: Edited to show how to achieve with loops and `append`.

Comment: oh, sorry !!! I found what are you talking about( I'm a lil bit slower on that 'Logic of syntax' yet )